# Can't convert TIFF images with ImageIO on RedHat server

Tags: java, server, redhat, tiff, javax.imageio

All

I'm trying to display TIFF images in web browsers but since they are not natively supported, I am converting them to a different format with javax.imageio.ImageIO using a function like

```
void convert(String filename, InputStream is, String outputType, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      if (filename.endsWith(".tif") || filename.endsWith(".tiff")) {
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
         if (image == null) {
            LOG.error("Failed to read image");
         } else {
            ImageIO.write(image, outputType, out);
         }
   }
```

This *works* on my **windows** desktop, my linux (**ubuntu**) desktop but does *not work* on my **RedHat** server 4.4.7 and 4.8.5. 
I'm getting the message "Failed to read image" in my logs (the resulting image variable is thus null).

I've been printing out the available format names to see what is at my disposal but only get "[JPG, jpg, bmp, BMP, gif, GIF, WBMP, png, PNG, jpeg, wbmp, JPEG]". So no tif, tiff, TIF or TIFF.

I've tried adding the following to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-tiff</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but to no avail.

Now I understand the ImageIO is based on plugins which need to be installed in the jvm but can't figure what is needed exactly and how to do it.

Could somebody please tell where I can find such plugin?

Thanks

William

PS I've tried with java7 and java8

PS2 I'm not sure if the following comment is relevant but I remember some years back having issues on a server because it had no graphic card installed, so some libraries were not installed because deemed unnecessary. My RedHat servers are run on virtual machines so I'm guessing they don't have any graphic card installed either. Maybe this could hint to a clue

PS3 I've also tried to add jai_codec to my dependencies because another old project had it in it's classpath. However I can't download it via maven. It seems the dependency does not exist anymore.
I've tried different groupId, artifcatId (with a dash and underscore) and version but none were working/downloading.

Comment: Good news is that tiff support is standard in java 9, as I have read somewhere. Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-tiff

Comment: Just a thought, Linux file names are case sensitive, are your image filenames ".TIF" by any chance?

Comment: @Joop it is good news but not for me, I can't upgrade to java 9 just yet :-(

Comment: @Duston no my filenames are lowercase and as I said it does work on my Linux Ubuntu (well actually it's linux mint) desktop but it is indeed something worth mentioning

Comment: *"Now I understand the ImageIO is based on plugins which need to be installed in the jvm but can't figure what is needed exactly and how to do it."* Please read [Deploying ImageIO plugins in a web app](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). Both the JAI and TwelveMonkeys projects are able to read TIFF files, but there's likely something wrong with how you deploy them.

Comment: Re: PS2: If your RedHat system was missing a display, that could cause problems, but I think you should see that explicitly in the logs (not just the "Failed to load..." message). Running the Java server in headless mode, will normally fix that.

Comment: @haraldK Thank You for pointing me too the document regarding deploying ImageIO in a web app. That solve my problem! 
I remember reading about it and trying it on my desktop but since it was working without it on the desktop, I didn't bother including it. It turns out it is needed. I should have known better!!!

Comment: @haraldK You might want to add the com.twelvemonkeys.imageio.servlet dependency in the Maven dependency section since it's needed to include the com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener listener